# How to add duplicates in python text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I have this text file which is ppe.txt where it contains this

```
GH,FS,25
KH,GL,35
GH,FS,35
```

how do I identify GH as they appeared twice and add the values so it becomes

```
GH,FS,60
KH,GL,35
```

is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You will need to write some code. Also, what happens if the last line in your file is FS,GH,35 or FS,XX,35 ?

Comment: read the file. split each line using comma as separator. merge the two first elements in a string, built a dictionary using this string as key. iterate over each line adding the value (3rd element) to the corresponding dictionary key, finally export the dictionary into csv.

Comment: can we just use only list to do this?

Comment: No the file format is fixed as GH and KH only can be in the 1st column followed by FS and GL then the quantity of them

Answer (score 0):

Open the file for reading. Split each line into 3 tokens. Form a tuple from the first 2 tokens and use that as the key to a dictionary (*result*). Append the int value of the 3rd token to the value of the tuple/key.

Finally, iterate over the dictionary's items and print the result.

```
result = {}

with open('ppe.txt') as ppe:
    for line in ppe:
        a, b, c = line.split(',')
        result.setdefault((a, b), []).append(int(c))

for (k1, k2), v in result.items():
    print(f'{k1},{k2},{sum(v)}')
```

**Output:**

```
GH,FS,60
KH,GL,35
```

Answer (score -1):

Open your file and add "a,b,c" as first line. These will be the column names.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("yourtxtfile.txt")

results = {}
for _, row in df.iterrows():
   results = results.get(row["a"], 0) + row["c"]

print(results)
// {'GH': 60, 'KH': 35}
```

This basically reads the csv file and inserts the values into a dictionary.

Ok so since we have complaints that it's not in a file format:

```
results.to_csv (r'mytextfile.txt', index = False, header=True)
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to give the required output

Comment: If you want to use the second column as part of the key simply concat row['a'] and row['b'] together with a delimiter in between as a key.

Comment: @MaikHasler doesnt matter if it's a txt file. His file has commas. Comma Seperated Values  (CSV). He can use .csv or .txt as long as his values are seperated by commas.

Comment: ya know this will be last time i help on site. you give negative points for me taking time to help.

Comment: @celphi You are right - I tested it out. Anyways I did not downvoted your answer.